# Windows 8.1 apps - RichEditBox baseline-based super- subscript

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, rtf, subscript, richeditbox

I've got a panel for text formatting and I've got to get sub- and superscript work but it can't be done by inserting \sub or \super into RTF (RTF is what I need in the end).
This is how I would set superscript by inserting \sub:

```
public void SetSuperscript()
{
    ITextSelection selectedText = _textbox.Document.Selection;
    if (selectedText != null)
    {
        ITextCharacterFormat charFormatting = selectedText.CharacterFormat;
        charFormatting.Superscript= FormatEffect.On;
        selectedText.CharacterFormat = charFormatting;
    }
}
```

Now I know I can do it like that as well:

```
public void SetSuperscript()
{
    ITextSelection selectedText = _textbox.Document.Selection;
    if (selectedText != null)
    {
        ITextCharacterFormat charFormatting = selectedText.CharacterFormat;
        charFormatting.Size /= 2;
        charFormatting.Position = charFormatting.Size;
        selectedText.CharacterFormat = charFormatting;
    }
}
```

and it works just as fine. The problem is when it comes to creating a subscript:

```
public void SetSubscript()
{
    ITextSelection selectedText = _textbox.Document.Selection;
    if (selectedText != null)
    {
        ITextCharacterFormat charFormatting = selectedText.CharacterFormat;
        charFormatting.Size /= 2;
        charFormatting.Position = -charFormatting.Size;
        selectedText.CharacterFormat = charFormatting;
    }
}
```

This code above throws an exception "Value does not fall within the expected range." and it's caused by this line:
`charFormatting.Position = -charFormatting.Size;`
I'm assigning there a negative value (which is allright according to the documentation) because I need the selected text to be lower than normal text by half of its height. What am I doing wrong?

Daniel